# Word - Start header Numeration at specific Point

Tags: microsoft-word, headers

I'd like to start my header 1 auto-numeration at a certain point. 
What I want to acchieve is a index like so:

```
Index
Literature
Chapter I: Introduction
Chapter II: Example
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create two separate Heading 1 style for that:

At first create some Heading 1 paragraphs and set the numbering as you need.

Then select one where you don't need formatting:

- in **Home** tab - **Styles** group click the "more" icon
- Selesct **Save selection as a new quick style**
- Type a name for your style (e.g. Heading 1 - no numbering), then  click Modify
- click **Format** - select **numbering** - select None, than OK twice